# Система счисления на с++

Tags: c++, алгоритм, системы-счисления, длинная-арифметика

> Системы счисления
> Дано целое неотрицательное число в I-ричной системе счисления. Вывести это число в J-ричной системе счисления. 2≤I, J≤36, для представления цифр 10..35 используются прописные латинские буквы А..Z соответственно, число разрядов входного числа не превышает 1000.
> Input format
> В первой строке находятся числа I и J (в десятичной системе счисления), во второй строке — число для перевода.
> Output format
> Вывести искомое число. Если число начинается с буквы, перед ней не должно быть нуля.
>
> Input
> 10 36
> 29234652
>
> Output
> HELLO

Comment: *Вывести это число в J-летней системе*  Интересно, что такое, например, 18-летняя система счисления? Совершеннолетняя?

Comment: вы то должны знать как авто перевод пашет. Это всего-лишь была `J-РIЧна` система. @Harry

Comment: @AlexGlebe Не поверите... Даже не подумал... Хотя регулярно сталкиваюсь с такими вещами в Интернете, но здесь...

Comment: а проблема в чём? длинная арифметика и вперёд. умножение длинного на короткое не так и сложно, сложение с коротким тоже.

Comment: @pavel Да вряд ли тут будет требоваться что-то за пределами `long long`...

Comment: не нашёл нигде чёткий ответ на переводы I->J. Предлагают только два перевода : `I->2->J` Может быть есть где-то алгоритм? @Harry

Comment: @AlexGlebe Ну да, сначала получение числового значения, потом опять перевод в новую строку. Более простой вариант есть только если J = I^n. Я когда-то для себя такой обобщенный вариант писал, но беда в том, что, как обычно, ни фига найти не могу...

Comment: @AlexGlebe, алгоритм прямого перевода есть - это длинная арифметика с основанием ***J***. Нужны две операции - умножение длинного на ***I***, сложение длинного с ***d***, ***0 <= d < I***. Это если за квадрат. У Кнута есть прямой перевод быстрее.

Comment: @Harry, там тысяча разрядов. Нужна длинная арифметика.

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте вашу попытку в вопрос. Руки чешутся вам помочь, но не могу без вашего кода.

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy, к сожелению кода нет и не знаю как его написать так как только учу с++. Вот и обратился к вам за помощью.

Comment: Алгоритм и сложность задачи очень большие, если вы не знаете как писать сложные программы, начните с простых.

Comment: @AlexGlebe, я пинимаю но ету задачу задали на школьном соревновании между 11-х класов

Comment: Эту задачу не сложно решить если вы нормально управляетесь с C++ и c умножением в столбик на листке бумаги. У школьников в 11 классе могут быть оба эти навыка. Для них задача не представляет сложности. Для вас, видимо, представляет. Или c С++ трудности или с арифметикой.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Да, прочел слишком :) быстро, не заметил. Пока не закрыли вопрос полностью, пишите ответ — у вас он явно будет нетривиальным, так что ради посмотреть на хороший ответ можно и пренебречь правилами, imho. Я даже отзываю ради этого свой голос за закрытие.

Answer (score 4):

Число хранится как вектор цифр, начиная с младших:

> ```
> "1234" -> [4, 3, 2, 1]
> ```

Над числом определена единственная операция "умножить_и_прибавить" - школьное умножение в столбик. Дополнительный параметр - основание системы счисления.

Преобразование состоит в чтении первого числа от старших цифр к младшим и накоплении во втором числе текущей суммы в новой системе счисления. Аналог схемы Горнера.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

// number = factor * number + term
void mul_add(int base, int factor, int term, std::vector<int> &number) {
    int carry = term;
    for (auto &digit : number) {
        const int p = digit * factor + carry;
        digit = p % base;
        carry = p / base;
    }
    for (; carry != 0; carry /= base) {
        number.push_back(carry % base);
    }
}

int value(char c) {
    return ('0' <= c && c <= '9') ? c - '0' : c - 'A' + 10;
}

char image(int d) {
    return static_cast<char>((d <= 9) ? '0' + d : 'A' + (d - 10));
}

int main() {
    int b1;
    int b2;
    std::string n1;
    std::cin >> b1 >> b2 >> n1;

    std::vector<int> n2 = {0};
    for (char c : n1) {
        mul_add(b2, b1, value(c), n2);
    }

    for(auto it = n2.rbegin(); it != n2.rend(); ++it) {
        std::cout << image(*it);
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

> ```
> $ g++ -std=c++17 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wwrite-strings -Wconversion temp.cpp
>
> $ echo 10 36 29234652 | ./a.out 
> HELLO
>
> $ echo 36 10 HELLO | ./a.out 
> 29234652
> ```